# How to close a dialog box using Java, that pops up during runtime?

Tags: java, eclipse, key

I am trying to make a project that performs OCR (image to text conversion).
I am using the AspriseOCR jar file and i set up my project accordingly. 
It works fine.

Whenever i run the project, when the call is made to aspriseOCR API, a dialog box pops up in windows asking if i want to go to their website. I need to automate the whole process. So i dont want this dialog box to appear.

Is there any way by which i can close this dialog box in my code itself, in case it appears? Is there a way i can press the Enter button (it will close accordingly). I am using Java, Eclipse.

Note: This is not on web browsers. So I cannot use Selenium related commands.

Edit:-
I tried to use this :-

`Robot r = new Robot(); 
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);`

But it wouldn't solve my problem as I need to add this in the API source code, which I do not have access to. Is there any other approach or method to close the dialog box?

So a part of the code is :-

```
`{
String s = ocr.recognize( new File[] {new File("C:\\work\\"+file)}, 
Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT); 
Robot robot; 
robot = new Robot(); 
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER); 
System.out.println("\n\n pressed enter\n\n"); 
System.out.println("Result:\n\n"+s); 
ocr.stopEngine();
}`
```

So when the control goes to the function ocr.recognize(...) the dialog box comes up and I do not have access to that source code which is present in that jar file.

Is there any way that I can parallelly run another thread which waits for the opening of this dialog box and closes it ( this thread parallelly running with ocr.recognize). Kindly let me know how to identify if a windows dialog box has been opened using java code.

Comment: what sort of dialog box? Need more info on that; is that a Windows dialog box? or sort of browser window?

Comment: It is a windows dialog box.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Robot class for this purpose as below:

```
    //if you want to press alt+f4; to close window or
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_F4);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ALT);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_F4);


    // to press enter

    Robot robot = new Robot();

    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

Comment: Hi. Thank you. But I already tried to use this, and it didn't work. 

Robot r = new Robot();
 r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
 r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

I got the following error:-

VK_ENTER cannot be resolved.

Comment: make sure you are using following imports `import java.awt.AWTException;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;`

Comment: Yes, it does press enter now, i missed out an import statement. 
Thank you.
However, my problem still persists. I will have to add the piece of code for pressing enter, in the API source code which I do not have access to.

So i need to now try another way to close the dialog box.

Comment: I don't understand; why can't you use  robot class from your code?

Comment: So the code is :-
`{
String s = ocr.recognize(
   new File[] {new File("C:\\work\\"+file)},
   Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, 
   Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);
    Robot robot;
  robot = new Robot();
     robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
     System.out.println("\n\n pressed enter\n\n");
 System.out.println("Result:\n\n"+s)
 ocr.stopEngine();}`

So the part where the dialog box comes up is when the control goes to the function ocr.recognize(...) and i do not have access to that source code which is present in that jar file.

Comment: so you can try to first call this `ocr.recognize( new File[] {new File("C:\\work\\"+file)}, Ocr.RECOGNIZE_TYPE_ALL, Ocr.OUTPUT_FORMAT_PLAINTEXT);` then use robot class after Assign it to `String s`

Comment: No, thats what i have done right now and it isnt working, 'cause the program halts until the user click yes or no from the dialog box which gets opened when it calls ocr.recognize(), and once the user clicks yes or no ( or presses enter) the rest of the code in ocr.recognize() is carried out and then control is returned to my program. So calling the robot class after ocr.recognize() in program won't work.